# Bluetooth Low Energy unique identifier

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, ios7

I am looking for a unique id accessible for a bluetooth low energy device from iOS.
I have 10 devices and i placed it in 10 different places. I exactly need to know to which device i am communicating irrespective of the iOS device i am using to connect.

In the iOS core bluetooth, a new UUID is assigned by iOS for my device. I am not able to uniquely identify the device.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17436980/a-way-to-uniquely-identify-a-btle-device ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the MAC address of the peripheral to generate a unique name in SCAN RESP. I guess you could also use this approach and maybe also put it in the advertisement data or in a message. (My peripheral was based on TI's 2540 SoC.)

Comment: At first how did you get MAC address of BLE peripheral ?
Can you please share the process to generate the unique name ?

Comment: I guess it depends on the BLE stack if you have access to the MAC address or not. As stated above my stack was TS2540 based. I'm sorry but I have no longer access to the code. But it was fairly simple for TI's BLE stack. Please note that you cannot get the MAC address from iOS CoreBluetooth. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge MAC/BDADDR is not accessible via CoreBluetooth, but I noticed that the "Device Information Service" profile (0x180A) contains a "System ID" attribute (0x2A23) which encodes the device's unique MAC/BDADDR address.  I don't know if it is mandatory for a BLE device to expose this service, however.

Answer (score 0):

Use Major and Minor properties in CLBeacon. Both are 4 char hex values.

They are located in advertisement data with UUID.

More info:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLBeacon_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLBeacon/major