# bluetooth low energy on standby mode in iOS?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have read the docs about the BLE for iOS, and i could see that every device has its UUID instead of  mac adress for the BLE.

My question ,in which there is no answer to on the docs, is- when you turn on the bluetooth on the device ( without opening any app) , so the device's bluetooth is on , what does it advertise then, and could I discover that device or get its UUID, while his bluetooth is on,*but without any app that is open.*

I am pretty sure that when the BLE is on, you can discover that device, or awake him, but I wonder what data can I get from him while its on without an app .
(same for Android.. )

Answer (score 1):

iOS does not advertise any Bluetooth Low Energy services that are visible to another iOS device without an app running.  Once an app advertises a service you will see additional services available - device information, time service, battery level.

If you are using different Bluetooth hardware to scan then you may see some advertisements without an app but the reported UUID of an iOS device changes every 15 minutes for privacy reasons - See this answer - [Corebluetooth, How to get a unique UUID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524871/corebluetooth-how-to-get-a-unique-uuid)

Comment: This is probably not true, because when you turn the bluetooth on the device, the mac for instance, can identify the device ,that means the device is discoverable. If you where right, whats the propose of the bluetooth button on the iDevices(the one you get when you swipe for the bottom of the screen and open the control center )

Comment: Aslo according to the docs, and my experience, the UUID had never changed, and was constant.

Comment: I assumed you were asking about BLE services that would be visible to another iOS device using Core Bluetooth.  The device may advertise legacy Bluetooth services, but these are not visible to Core Bluetooth.  There may also be Apple services (such as the hotspot service) which are visible to iOS and OSX but are filtered from the Core Bluetooth library (iBeacon advertisements are not delivered via Core Bluetooth, for example).  The purpose of the Bluetooth button is to turn off the Bluetooth radio - this affects both Core Bluetooth and legacy (handsfree for example)

Comment: If you are using a non iOS device to look for iOS devices then the case may be different, but the UUID will still change unless you are paired with the device

Comment: I am using hardware to identify if a device is in a certain area, and i was thinking to identify that with the ble when its turned on, without an app..