# CoreBluetooth: the UUID of a peripheral is an inherent attribute of a device?

Tags: android, ios, uuid, core-bluetooth

I use **CoreBluetooth** to connect my iPhone with a device equipped with **Bluetooth 4.0**.

I print its (as a peripheral) UUID :

```
<CBPeripheral: 0x1742fca80, identifier = B148AD69-1FC7-498C-016F-33BA3BE041A3, name = HMSoft, state = disconnected>
```

I wonder whether this *identifier* is an **inherent attribute of a device**.

Since I use the following code in **android** to get its **UUID** which is different from what I get using **CoreBluetooth** in iPhone:

```
 BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
 for (ParcelUuid uuid : device.getUuids()) {
                    Log.d("UUID", uuid.getUuid().toString());
                }
```

( I connect with the same device but the print UUID is different).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Corebluetooth, How to get a unique UUID?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524871/corebluetooth-how-to-get-a-unique-uuid)

Comment: **UUID** of a peripheral is unique in every scanning, but iPhone and Android scanned different result.

Comment: That's right. A given iOS device will always see the same UUID for a given peripheral but different iOS devices will get a different UUID for the same peripheral and the UUID is not the MAC address - it is created by iOS

Comment: *android* has API get the peripheral's mac address while **coreBluetooth** in *iOS* seems there is no public API. How to get the unique identifier that has consistency for both *iOS* and *android* ?

Comment: You can't - iOS doesn't expose that identifier.  I did see one answer where the device information characteristic of the device contained the MAC,but that is probably device dependent and requires that you connect to the device to read the characteristic

Answer (score 0):

Identifier in CBPeripheral is a randomly generated Unique identifier. This gets varied over time. In case of a CBPeripheral, we need to know about two kinds of UUIDs. One is ServiceUUID and other is CharacteristicUUID. Each peripheral broadcast data over each service. A single service can have more than one characteristics. For eg. a device information service can have device name, device version etc as its characteristics.

See the following image for a better understanding [CBPeripheral](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/Art/TreeOfServicesAndCharacteristics_Remote_2x.png). The [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothOverview/CoreBluetoothOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH2-SW1) speaks well on this.

Answer (score 0):

My first answer, so I hope I won't make a fool of myself ;-)

`BluetoothDevice.getUuids()`:
Returns the supported features (UUIDs) of the remote device. I.e. UUIDs of services advertised by the device, not UUID of the device itself.
I'm currently looking myself for an Android way to get the UUID of a discovered BLE device...